# Copy a file in Azure Devops Artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

In one of stage I am downloading artifacts for (win,linux and mac agent) to my Blob storage using Azure CLI and I have the folder structure like this in Azure blob container after I download. In the bin folders I have files and folders and few dlls.

```
MyBlobContainer --> Project_x64-linux-->bin
               ---> Project_x64-mac--> bin
               ---> project_x4-win--> bin
```

Downloading is done by this inline script in an YAML AZure Cli Task:

```
 inlineScript: az storage blob upload-batch -d "$(BlobContainer)/ProjectName/$(DeploymentVersion)/Project_x64-$(osSuffix)" --account-name "myStorageAccount" -s "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Project_x64-$(osSuffix)"
```

In the same stage when I debug my Build.SourceDirectory by calling `Get-ChildItem $(Build.SourcesDirectory) -Recurse`

I get all the child directories and files. One of the file I see in debug is in this directory:

```
Directory: D:\a\1\s\packages\KinectSDK\windows-desktop\amd64\release\bin

-a----        3/16/2021   8:57 PM       24038776 onnxruntime.dll
```

I am interested in copying this dll in the bin folder of my downloaded artifacts above. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [Copy files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) before the Azure Cli Task to copy the onnxruntime.dll file to the bin folder of the artfacts. See below:

```
steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Project_x64-$(osSuffix)/bin'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/packages/KinectSDK/windows-desktop/amd64/release/bin'
    Contents: onnxruntime.dll
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Project_x64-$(osSuffix)/bin'
    flattenFolders: true
  condition: eq(variables['osSuffix'], 'win')
```

You can also copy the onnxruntime.dll file in the Azure CLI task using `Copy-Item` command. See below:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Subscription-Azure'
    scriptType: ps
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
    
     Copy-Item "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/packages/KinectSDK/windows-desktop/amd64/release/bin/onnxruntime.dll" -Destination "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Project_x64-$(osSuffix)/bin"
      
     az storage blob upload-batch ....
```

You can also using Az Cli command to copy the `onnxruntime.dll` to your Blob storage directly.

[AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-upload?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#upload-a-file) command:

```
azcopy copy '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/packages/KinectSDK/windows-desktop/amd64/release/bin/onnxruntime.dll' 'https://mystorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/mycontainer/ProjectName/$(DeploymentVersion)/Project_x64-$(osSuffix)/bin/onnxruntime.dll'
```

Comment: i think Copy File will not work with linux and mac agent..isnt it_

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint I have tested. Copy File task works with linux and mac agent perfectly too.

Comment: it fails for linux and mac saying file is not present while for windows it works. it gives error as "Not found SourceFolder: /Users/runner/work/1/s/packages/KinectSDK/windows-desktop/amd64/release/bin"

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint Could you debug your Build.SourceDirectory in Linux and Mac agent, to check if the onnxruntime.dll still exists in the folder `s/packages/KinectSDK/windows-desktop/amd64/release/bin`. The file might exist in a different folder  in Linux and Mac agent?

Comment: i don't get for other folders but what if I want to copy only when osSuffix is win and not linux and mac. How can I put a condition in here?

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint You can put a [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) like this `condition: eq(variables['osSuffix'], 'win')`. See above update.