# Unable to copy all files/folders to Azure Storage from DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-storage, azcopy

I am using Azure DevOps pipeline release to copy files from build artifact to Azure storage container.

I am using a tool called "Azure file copy" (it's azcopy I believe), which is the only one I can find in the market place. It connects using my subscription and able to copy files just fine.

However, it always include the root folder name -- I specified the location of the source like this "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_MyProject Build/drop/portal_unzip/content/D_C/a/1/s/Portal/obj/Release/net5.0/browser-wasm/PubTmp/Out/wwwroot"

And when it copies the files and folder to the destination, it creates a folder "wwwroot" and put everything under that folder. I can't have this wwwroot folder. Basically I need everything under wwwroot copied over to the container directly.

My current workaround is to copy individual subfolders, as well as the files under wwwroot in multiple steps in the pipeline. This is really slow as it needs to establish azure connection for each step.

Is there a way to make this one single step?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the command which you have used? Along with the azcopy output file from the client

Comment: I am not using any command, this is all wizard-driven -- filling out info in textboxes. I am not using YAML. What is azcopy output file from the client?

Comment: Use your Source: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_MyProject Build/drop" till here only 
Reference under "Step1: Azure File Copy task" : https://praveenkumarsreeram.com/2021/04/14/azure-devops-copy-files-from-git-repository-to-azure-storage-account/ 



You can use this SO thread as well there is different ways of files transfer to blob storage:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66664519/copy-a-file-in-azure-devops-artifacts